# Creating sobject using if i know object api name in string

Tags: describesobject

I have an sObject which I know it's api name (without namespace prefix).

How can I create a reference to it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [Dynamic DML](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_dynamic_dml.htm) and family of Describe() methods

```
String typeName = 'Account';

Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(typeName);
sObject obj = targetType.newSObject();

// now either cast it to Account and proceed
// Account a = (Account) obj;
// a.Name = 'Abc';

// or use sObject's generic get() and put() methods
obj.put('Name', 'Abc'); // use targetType.getDescribe().fields.getMap() to obtain map of all available field names
insert obj;
```

Global describe should return all objects visible to you (except if you don't have a license for managed package etc. standard visibility stuff), I have no problems retrieving these 2 installed in my org:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
System.debug(gd.get('c2g__codaInvoice__c'));
System.debug(gd.get('chttrunfollow__UnfollowRule__c'));
```

Comment: Will it also work for managed package? Actually I am already having namespace prefix.

Comment: It should! check out the updated answer. Just iterate over the map throwing stuff out to System.debug()? Essentially it's not different than what Eclipse IDE, Data Loader, Apex Explorer etc tools do... In fact I think when you write a managed package and you need to work on "not your" objects you're encouraged to use dynamic DML. Make no assumptions that even Accounts exist in the target org because somebody might want to install your app on Platform Edition which I think doesn't have all these SFA objects.

Comment: It will work for managed packages, but BE WARNED, if your code is in Namespace 1 (NS1), and has an object called `NS1__ObjA__c`, and in a customer's local org there is an object called `ObjA__c`, then `NS1__ObjA__c` will not show up in the result of `getGlobalDescribe()` from within NS1 --- it will be overwritten by `ObjA__c`. Even `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('NS1__ObjA__c')` will return a reference to `ObjA__c` in the local namespace! So beware.

Answer (score 0):

```
Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Case').getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Billing').getRecordTypeId();
system.debug('**devRecordTypeId*' + devRecordTypeId);
```